# Default value for datetimepicker input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Using Laravel 5.7 I want to set the default date to today if we are not editing entry (only for newones). (If $item->date does not exist, set $item->date to today's date, otherwise print $item->date which is in database)
My code:

```
<input type="text" id="date " class="form-control" name="date " placeholder="Date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }} ?? {{ old('date ') ? : $item->date  }}">
```

The problem is my code always displays today date.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```html
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="date" 
    placeholder="Date" 
    value="{{ old('date', $item->date) ?? date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}"
>
```